# How to count the number of elements in this particular object

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I am making a call to an API and the response is somehow what I expect. However, I want to count the number of elements returned  and I can not do it. This is what I think is important from the code.

Call in Vue component

```
data(){
    return {
      messages: {}
    }
  },
loadMessages(){
      axios.get("api/messagesmenu")
        .then((data) => { this.messages = data.data})
    }
```

Api controller

```
public function index(){

    $messages = Message::all()->where('read_at', NULL);

    if(isset($messages)){
        foreach($messages as $message){
            $from = User::find($message->from_id);
            $message->fromPrenom = $from->first_name;
            $message->fromNom = $from->last_name;
            $message->fromImage = $from->user_image;
        }
    }else{
        $messages = [];
    }


    return $messages;
}
```

Type of response from the API

```
{"3":{"id":560,"from_id":2,"to_id":1,"content":"tgr","created_at":"2019-07-15 16:59:03","read_at":null,"fromPrenom":"abdel1","fromNom":"Hidalgo","fromImage":"user2-160x160.png"}}
```

I want to count the number of objects I obtain. if (in vue component) I do

```
this.messages.length
```

it returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const messages = {"3":{"id":560,"from_id":2,"to_id":1,"content":"tgr","created_at":"2019-07-15 16:59:03","read_at":null,"fromPrenom":"abdel1","fromNom":"Hidalgo","fromImage":"user2-160x160.png"}}

console.log(Object.keys(messages).length) // 1
```

Or in your code:

```
...
.then((data) => { 
  this.messages = data.data
  console.log(Object.keys(this.messages).length)
})
```

Comment: Yes, it works. It took me a while because I had a different variable name, but it works nice